# No funcionan los OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, eventos, onclick, onclicklistener

Estoy programando una aplicación Android que empezó un alumno de prácticas antes que yo y he tenido que implementar en un elemento en árbol que hizo él un botón para que se abra la ubicación en Google Maps de cada elemento del árbol.
El problema es que al hacer click en el ImageButton (llamado imBt_abrirMaps), no ejecuta el OnClickListener, directamente es como si no hicieses nada.

```
nodeItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_work_24);
        nodeItem.setText(nInstalacion);
        TreeNode instalacion = new TreeNode(nodeItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.tree_element, 25));
        nodeItem.imBt_abrirMaps.setOnClickListener(v -> abrirMaps(nInstalacion, String.valueOf(latitud), String.valueOf(longitud), v));

        zonaItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_border_outer_24);
        zonaItem.setText(nZona);
        zonaItem.imBt_abrirMaps.setOnClickListener(v -> abrirMaps(nZona, String.valueOf(latitud), String.valueOf(longitud), v));
        TreeNode zona = new TreeNode(zonaItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.tree_element, 50));

        emplazamientoItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24);
        emplazamientoItem.setText(nEmplaz);
        TreeNode emplazamiento = new TreeNode(emplazamientoItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.tree_element, 75));
        emplazamientoItem.imBt_abrirMaps.setOnClickListener(v -> abrirMaps(nEmplaz, String.valueOf(latitud), String.valueOf(longitud), v));
```

La clase entera es esta:

````
package com.app.gmao_app.ui.activos;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.app.gmao_app.IconTreeItem;
import com.app.gmao_app.Interface.APIService;
import com.app.gmao_app.MainActivity;
import com.app.gmao_app.Model.Activo;
import com.app.gmao_app.Model.Emplazamiento;
import com.app.gmao_app.MyHolder;
import com.app.gmao_app.R;
import com.unnamed.b.atv.model.TreeNode;
import com.unnamed.b.atv.view.AndroidTreeView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class FragmentActivos extends Fragment  {

    private ActivosViewModel activosViewModel;
    private ScrollView cajaArbol;
    LinearLayout arbolLayout;
    private EditText marca_tipo;
    private EditText modelo;
    private EditText nombre;
    private Button buscar;
    private IconTreeItem nodeItem;
    private IconTreeItem zonaItem;
    private IconTreeItem emplazamientoItem;
    private IconTreeItem activoItem;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        System.out.println("ON CREATE VIEW ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        activosViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ActivosViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activos, container, false);
        View vElementoArbol = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tree_element, container, false);

        nodeItem = new IconTreeItem();
        zonaItem = new IconTreeItem();
        emplazamientoItem = new IconTreeItem();
        activoItem = new IconTreeItem();

        nodeItem.imBt_abrirMaps = (ImageButton) vElementoArbol.findViewById(R.id.imBt_abrirMaps);
        zonaItem.imBt_abrirMaps = (ImageButton) vElementoArbol.findViewById(R.id.imBt_abrirMaps);
        emplazamientoItem.imBt_abrirMaps = (ImageButton) vElementoArbol.findViewById(R.id.imBt_abrirMaps);
        activoItem.imBt_abrirMaps = (ImageButton) vElementoArbol.findViewById(R.id.imBt_abrirMaps);

        cajaArbol = (ScrollView) root.findViewById(R.id.cajaArbolActivos);
        arbolLayout= (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.arbolLayout);

        marca_tipo = root.findViewById(R.id.cajaMarcaTipo);
        modelo = root.findViewById(R.id.cajaModelo);
        nombre = root.findViewById(R.id.cajaNombreActivos);
        buscar = root.findViewById(R.id.botonBuscarActivos);

        buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                arbolLayout.removeAllViews();
                getEmplazamientosPorDatos();
            }
        });
        activosViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {

            }
        });
        getEmplazamientos();

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    // Construccion del menu en arbol
    private void generarArbol(String nInstalacion, String nZona, String nEmplaz, List<String> nActivo, List<Activo> codActivos, double latitud, double longitud) {
        System.out.println("GENERAR ÁRBOL -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        
        TreeNode raiz = TreeNode.root();

        nodeItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_work_24);
        nodeItem.setText(nInstalacion);
        TreeNode instalacion = new TreeNode(nodeItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.tree_element, 25));
        nodeItem.imBt_abrirMaps.setOnClickListener(v -> abrirMaps(nInstalacion, String.valueOf(latitud), String.valueOf(longitud), v));

        zonaItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_border_outer_24);
        zonaItem.setText(nZona);
        zonaItem.imBt_abrirMaps.setOnClickListener(v -> abrirMaps(nZona, String.valueOf(latitud), String.valueOf(longitud), v));
        TreeNode zona = new TreeNode(zonaItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.tree_element, 50));

        emplazamientoItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24);
        emplazamientoItem.setText(nEmplaz);
        TreeNode emplazamiento = new TreeNode(emplazamientoItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.tree_element, 75));
        emplazamientoItem.imBt_abrirMaps.setOnClickListener(v -> abrirMaps(nEmplaz, String.valueOf(latitud), String.valueOf(longitud), v));

        // Fin
        emplazamiento.setClickListener(new TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value) {
                //((MainActivity) requireActivity()).showInMap(latitud, longitud);
            }
        });
        // Obtencion de todos los activos de un mismo emplazamiento
        final int[] i = {0};
        for(String activo : nActivo) {
            activoItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shape);
            activoItem.setText(activo);
            TreeNode nodoActivo = new TreeNode(activoItem).setViewHolder(new MyHolder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.tree_element, 100));
            activoItem.imBt_abrirMaps.setOnClickListener(v -> abrirMaps(activo, String.valueOf(latitud), String.valueOf(longitud), v));
            Activo currentActivo = codActivos.get(i[0]);
            nodoActivo.setClickListener(new TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value) {
                    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).fichActivos(currentActivo.getCodActivo());
                }
            });
            emplazamiento.addChildren(nodoActivo);
            i[0]++;
        }
        // Fin
        instalacion.addChildren(zona);
        zona.addChildren(emplazamiento);
        raiz.addChildren(instalacion);
        AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), raiz);
        arbolLayout.addView(tView.getView());
    }
    // Fin

    // Llamadas emplazamientos
    private void getEmplazamientos() {
        APIService APIServiceApi = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).retrofitSetup().create(APIService.class);
        Call<List<Emplazamiento>> call = APIServiceApi.getEmplazamientosConNombres();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Emplazamiento>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Emplazamiento>> call, Response<List<Emplazamiento>> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Codigo: "+response.code());
                    return;
                }
                List<Emplazamiento> emplazamientosList = response.body();
                for(Emplazamiento emplazamiento: emplazamientosList) {
                    // ACTIVOS
                    ArrayList<String> listaActivos = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<Activo> listaCodigos = new ArrayList<>();
                    Call<List<Activo>> callActivos = APIServiceApi.getActivos();
                    callActivos.enqueue(new Callback<List<Activo>>() {
                        @Override
                        synchronized public void onResponse(Call<List<Activo>> call, Response<List<Activo>> response) {
                            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                                System.out.println("Codigo: "+response.code());
                                return;
                            }
                            for(Activo activo : response.body()) {
                                if(activo.getNombreEmplazamiento().equals(emplazamiento.getNombre())) {
                                    listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                    listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                }
                            }
                            // Arbol
                            if(!listaActivos.isEmpty()) {
                                generarArbol(emplazamiento.getNombreInstalacion(),emplazamiento.getNombreZona(),emplazamiento.getNombre(),listaActivos, listaCodigos, emplazamiento.getGpsLatitud(), emplazamiento.getGpsLongitud());
                            }
                            // Fin
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<Activo>> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                    // FIN
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Emplazamiento>> call, Throwable t) {
                //System.out.println(t.getMessage());
                System.out.println("HA FALLADO LA CONEXIÓN");
            }
        });
    }
    // Fin

    // Llamadas emplazamientos para búsqueda por datos
    private void getEmplazamientosPorDatos() {
        APIService APIServiceApi = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).retrofitSetup().create(APIService.class);
        Call<List<Emplazamiento>> call = APIServiceApi.getEmplazamientosConNombres();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Emplazamiento>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Emplazamiento>> call, Response<List<Emplazamiento>> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("Codigo: "+response.code());
                    return;
                }
                List<Emplazamiento> emplazamientosList = response.body();
                for(Emplazamiento emplazamiento: emplazamientosList) {
                    // ACTIVOS
                    ArrayList<String> listaActivos = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<Activo> listaCodigos = new ArrayList<>();
                    Call<List<Activo>> callActivos = APIServiceApi.getActivos();
                    callActivos.enqueue(new Callback<List<Activo>>() {
                        @Override
                        synchronized public void onResponse(Call<List<Activo>> call, Response<List<Activo>> response) {
                            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                                System.out.println("Codigo: "+response.code());
                                return;
                            }
                            for(Activo activo : response.body()) {
                                if(activo.getNombreEmplazamiento().equals(emplazamiento.getNombre())) {
                                    // Comprobacion de los criterios de búsqueda
                                    if(marca_tipo.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                        if(modelo.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                            if(activo.getNombre().contentEquals(nombre.getText())) {
                                                listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            if(nombre.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                                if(activo.getNombreModelo().contentEquals(modelo.getText())) {
                                                    listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                    listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                if(activo.getNombre().contentEquals(nombre.getText())) {
                                                    if(activo.getNombreModelo().contentEquals(modelo.getText())) {
                                                        listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                        listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if(modelo.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                        if(marca_tipo.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                            if(activo.getNombre().contentEquals(nombre.getText())) {
                                                listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            if(nombre.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                                if(activo.getNombreMarcaTipo().contentEquals(marca_tipo.getText())) {
                                                    listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                    listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                if(activo.getNombre().contentEquals(nombre.getText())) {
                                                    if(activo.getNombreMarcaTipo().contentEquals(marca_tipo.getText())) {
                                                        listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                        listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if (nombre.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                        if(marca_tipo.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                            if(activo.getNombreModelo().contentEquals(modelo.getText())) {
                                                listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                            } else {
                                                if(activo.getNombreModelo().contentEquals(modelo.getText())) {
                                                    if(activo.getNombreMarcaTipo().contentEquals(marca_tipo.getText())) {
                                                        listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                        listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if (activo.getNombreMarcaTipo().contentEquals(marca_tipo.getText())) {
                                            if(activo.getNombre().contentEquals(nombre.getText())) {
                                                if(activo.getNombreModelo().contentEquals(modelo.getText())) {
                                                    listaActivos.add(activo.getNombre());
                                                    listaCodigos.add(activo);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // Fin
                                }
                            }
                            // Arbol
                            if(!listaActivos.isEmpty()) {
                                generarArbol(emplazamiento.getNombreInstalacion(),emplazamiento.getNombreZona(),emplazamiento.getNombre(),listaActivos, listaCodigos, emplazamiento.getGpsLatitud(), emplazamiento.getGpsLongitud());
                            }
                            // Fin
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<List<Activo>> call, Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
                    // FIN
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Emplazamiento>> call, Throwable t) {
                //System.out.println(t.getMessage());
                System.out.println("HA FALLADO LA CONEXIÓN");
            }
        });
    }

    public void abrirMaps(String latitud, String longitud, String nombre, View v){
        String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + latitud + "," + longitud + "(" + nombre + ")";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // Fin
}```
````

La clase IconTreeItem es esta:

```
package com.app.gmao_app;

import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class IconTreeItem {
    public int icon;
    public String text;
    public ImageButton imBt_abrirMaps;

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public ImageButton getImBt_abrirMaps() {
        return imBt_abrirMaps;
    }

    public void setImBt_abrirMaps(ImageButton imBt_abrirMaps) {
        this.imBt_abrirMaps = imBt_abrirMaps;
    }
}
```

Y el XML del layout de cada nodo del árbol es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/treeview_left_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/treeview_right_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/treeview_top_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/treeview_bottom_padding">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_elementoArbol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_elementoArbol"
        android:contentDescription="icono del elemento del árbol"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_elementoArbol"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:text="List Item"
        android:textColor="@color/lightGray"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imBt_abrirMaps"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imBt_abrirMaps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_on_24"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_elementoArbol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_elementoArbol"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer la llamada de la siguiente manera

```
public void abrirMaps(String latitud, String longitud){
        String uri =  String.format("geo:%s,%s", latitud, longitud);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Si el problema no es el método, que sí que funciona porque lo llamo también en otras clases. El problema es que no se hace la llamada cuando pulsas el botón. De todas formas probé a utilizar tu método y tampoco funcionaba.

Answer (score 0):

Estas asignando un `ImageView` a un objeto `IconTreeItem`  y tratas de configurar un listener, esto no podrà funcionar.

Debes obtener la referencia del `ImageView` en el layout y posteriormente configurar el listener, pero en este caso no es un `ImageView` si no un `ImageButton`.

```
//Obtiene referencia en layout
ImageButton myImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imBt_abrirMaps);
//Define listener 
 myImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           abrirMaps(nZona, String.valueOf(latitud), String.valueOf(longitud), v));
        }
 });
```

Comment: Si te he entendido bien, me estás diciendo que estaba asignando un ImageButton a un ImageView. Si es eso a lo que te referías, ya lo corregí y cambié el ImageView del layout por un ImageButton, que no me había dado cuenta de que en el layout había puesto mal eso.
De todas formas, ya cambiado eso, sigue sin funcionar.